# Some map annotations with custom images not displayed in Android app

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I'm developing an Android app in Appcelerator Studio.

In the app I have a map which displays annotations with different custom images. The annotations are created this way:

```
annotation = map.createAnnotation({
   image: 'images/pin' + myNumber + '.png',
   latitude: myLat,
   longitude: myLong,
   title: myTitle
});
```

Almost all of the annotations are displayed, but there are a few which for some reason are invisible. I've verified that 'images/pin' + myNumber + '.png' is the actual path to the image I want to display.

Image which is displayed:

[image]

Image which is NOT displayed:

[image]

### Edit

Things getting weirder.

For testing purpose I created two ImageViews with the image property set to 'images/pin3.png' and 'images/pin163.png' respectively. Both images are displayed. But, as stated, when setting 'images/pin163.png' to an annotation's image property, it is invisble.

I would greatly appreciate your help as I don't have any idea what the issue might be.

### Edit 2 with tests:

Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1:

- Pin 3 is displayed
- Pin 163 is NOT displayed

Sony Experia Z, Android 4.4:

- Pin 3 is displayed
- Pin 163 is NOT displayed

Sony Experia Z, Android 5.Something:

- Pin 3 is displayed
- Pin 163 is also displayed

Comment: Try to add a slash before images, e.g, `/images/pin' + myNumber + '.png`, Android is very sensible about it.

Comment: I've tried that @VictorCasé. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working.

Instead of setting the annotation's image property, I create a view, set the view's backgroundImage property to my image and then assign the view to the annotation's customView property.

```
var customAnnotationView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundImage: 'images/pin' + myNumber + '.png',
});

var annotation = map.createAnnotation({
   customView: customAnnotationView,
   latitude: myLat,
   longitude: myLong,
   title: myTitle
});
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me. This issue should really be reported to JIRA I think

Comment: If this is still an issue, it definitely should. Will you do it @YahyaUddin?

Comment: I will probably do it eventually. But just really don't have time to create MCVE just now.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an Android application in Appcelerator Studio me too and in my project there were a lot of images; in particolare case, I attempted to load many images in the same controller and often not all of them were showed.
At the end, I found that the reason of this issue, it was the size of image.
In fact, if I resized them, all were showed.

I hope that my exeperience will be helpful.

Let me know.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't believe that's the issure here as the images that are not displayed are the exact same size as the images that are displayed.

Comment: The problem is not directly linked at the size of images but at Android's memory management. It's as Android not handle correctly the device's memory with images. Take a look at http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/ for

Comment: Sounds spooky. I have about 160 annotations being displayed and the images are ~5 kb each on disk. If the system can't handle that..

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try to riduce the number of annotations. For example, if you load 120 annotations (some of them are not showed with your actual configuration) and you don't have any trouble will confim that your problem is the memory.

Comment: The image for pin3 is displayed, the image for pin163 is not - regardless of how many pins/annotations I have on the map. However: if I set the image for pin163 to an ImageView and add that in a random view in the app, the image is displayed. Super weird imo.

Comment: Sounds like a plausible theory but I'm not sure what to do about it. I don't believe I can make the images much smaller. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know if you use this Android's tool for image, but resize automatically your icons in each format. http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example

For example i tried to resize your first icon and from 4.9KB became 548byte. Subdivide your new images in each folder and automatically Android use the correct size. 
Please if my answer is helpful for you mark it.

Comment: Thanks! :) if you would like contact me, you can find info on my profile. Regards

Comment: I updated my Android version and now the images are displayed properly. I wonder what black magic is going on underneath the surface. I will mark your answer as it will very likely help out people in similar situations. Thanks for taking time sharing your experience :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: @Maxdvlpr you have marked Giordana his answer, but you say using a different Android version (on your phone or as API to build with?) was the solution. Could you create an answer for your question with the exact solution and accept it yourself so other users can see what the correct answer is?

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen maybe it's not 100% correct marking Giordano's answer, but I do think it can help people with similar issues. Due to having updated the Android version on my device I cannot replicate the bug. Have you ever experienced this? Can you replicate it?

Comment: Ok, maybe is not the correct answer, but i think that it will be helpful. It is my experience in a similar problem.

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar problem on Android. Make sure that you have put the images with the correct resolution in the density folders:

```
/Resources/android/images/res-mdpi/
/Resources/android/images/res-hdpi/
/Resources/android/images/res-xhdpi/
/Resources/android/images/res-xxhdpi/
```

Comment: All images are in their respective folders as you suggest. Double checked just to be sure.